# Destroy session of user when disabled by admin?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Imagine you are Admin, now you decide to disable or remove a user.
If that user is logged in and is working with system, must be return to login page in soon (while he send first next request after kick by admin).
What should i do?

Comment: This is your interview question?

Comment: Why? I realy need to answer.

Comment: I searched for solve but not found any good answer :((

Comment: I attempted to explain problem obvious but you think that is "interview question" :(((

Answer (score 1):

In the auth filter, if the user is not a guest - check if he is disabled; if so, log him out.

This will not log him out if he requests a public (non-auth protected) route.. but what would be the point anyway, since it doesnt matter if the user is logged in or not.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Comment: When you change the user password or disable or remove him it should be check. I guess, maybe is there any help in laravel. thank you.   my question is not a spam please be more kind.

Comment: @armani Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve? If you want to log the user out, a simple `Auth::logout()` will suffice. A password change and user disabling are two completely unrelated events.

Comment: oh you don't understand me, For example, i am admin and i decide to change your password or decide to remove you from database. if in the same time you are login in system, you must be kick.